# Type 'MPCManager' does not conform to protocol 'MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate'

Tags: swift

in my swift 2 app i get this two errors:

> Protocol requires function
>   'advertiser(_:didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:withContext:invitationHandler:)'
>   with type '(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:
>   MCPeerID, withContext: NSData?, invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession)
>   -> Void) -> Void'

AND

> Candidate has non-matching type '(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser,
>   didReceiveInvitationFromPeer: MCPeerID, withContext: NSData?,
>   invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession!) -> Void) -> ()'

How can i solve this problems?

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity


protocol MPCManagerDelegate {
    func foundPeer()

    func lostPeer()

    func invitationWasReceived(fromPeer: String)

    func connectedWithPeer(peerID: MCPeerID)
}

class MPCManager: NSObject, MCSessionDelegate, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate {
    var session: MCSession!
    var peer: MCPeerID!
    var browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser!
    var advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser!

    var foundPeers = [MCPeerID]()
    var invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession!) -> Void
    var delegate: MPCManagerDelegate?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        invitationHandler(false, nil)

        peer = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name)

        session = MCSession(peer: peer)
        session.delegate = self

        browser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: peer, serviceType: "appcoda-mpc")
        browser.delegate = self

        advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peer, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: "appcoda-mpc")
        advertiser.delegate = self
    }



    func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) {
        foundPeers.append(peerID)

        delegate?.foundPeer()
    }

    func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, lostPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        for (index, aPeer) in EnumerateSequence(foundPeers){
            if aPeer == peerID {
                foundPeers.removeAtIndex(index)
                break
            }
        }

        delegate?.lostPeer()
    }

    func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, didNotStartBrowsingForPeers error: NSError) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


    func advertiser(advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: NSData?, invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession!) -> Void) {
        self.invitationHandler = invitationHandler

        delegate?.invitationWasReceived(peerID.displayName)
    }

    func advertiser(advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didNotStartAdvertisingPeer error: NSError) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }



    func session(session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChangeState state: MCSessionState) {
        switch state{
        case MCSessionState.Connected:
            print("Connected to session: \(session)")
            delegate?.connectedWithPeer(peerID)

        case MCSessionState.Connecting:
            print("Connecting to session: \(session)")

        default:
            print("Did not connect to session: \(session)")
        }
    }

    func sendData(dictionaryWithData dictionary: Dictionary<String, String>, toPeer targetPeer: MCPeerID) -> Bool {
        let dataToSend = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dictionary)
        let peersArray = NSArray(object: targetPeer) as! [MCPeerID]

        do {
            try session.sendData(dataToSend, toPeers: peersArray, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        let dictionary: [String: AnyObject] = ["data": data, "fromPeer": peerID]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("receivedMPCDataNotification", object: dictionary)
    }

    func session(session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withProgress progress: NSProgress) { }

    func session(session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, atURL localURL: NSURL, withError error: NSError?) { }

    func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveStream stream: NSInputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) { }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To omit the error, you can initialize invitationHandler property like the following.

```
var invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession) -> Void = { success, session in }
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback parameter `invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession!) -> Void` has one of it's parameter unwrapped. Remove exclamation mark `!` after MCSession datatype. This makes method not matching the original delegate method, and Swift can't find **required** delegate method of this protocol.

**Updated**

Change declaration of callback

```
var invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession) -> Void = { status, session in }
```

In the init method, instead of nil you must pass a initialised MCSession instance

```
invitationHandler(false, session)
```

Comment: thanks, but now i have only a new error: "Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'MCSession'" on this line         invitationHandler(false, nil)

Comment: than i get the error: Property 'self.invitationHandler' not initialized at super.init call

Comment: hmm, ok. check it now.